# How do I use ioctl() to set FIONBIO on a socket in VxWorks?

Tags: c++, sockets, vxworks

VxWorks's standard method to set FIONBIO is with `ioctl()`, not `fcntl()`. The documentation for FIONBIO gives this as an example, which obviously isn't going to compile, because `on` has no datatype:

```
on = TRUE;
status = ioctl (sFd, FIONBIO, &on);
```

I've seen example usage around the net that says to use something like this (which is essentially the same thing):

```
int on = 1;
ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &on);
```

However, the documentation says the prototype for `ioctl()` is `ioctl(int, int, int)`, and I get errors about unable to convert `int*` to `int`. If I pass the value as an `int`, I just get a fatal kernel task-level exception.

This is my current code:

```
int SetBlocking(int sockfd, bool blocking)
{
  int nonblock = !blocking;
  return ioctl(sockfd, FIONBIO, &nonblock);
}
```

which returns the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from `int*' to `int'
initializing argument 3 of `int ioctl(int, int, int)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found it here.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.os.vxworks/35LLNr2PzhQ/ZT7FGNZN0MUJ)

Looks like I just need to cast the `int*` to `int`. I can't use c-style casting, so I used `reinterpret_cast`.

```
int SetBlocking(int sockfd, bool blocking)
{
  int nonblock = !blocking;

  return ioctl(sockfd,
    FIONBIO,
    reinterpret_cast<int>(&nonblock));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This link http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_ioctl.html suggests

```
 return ioctl(sockfd, FIONBIO, (char*) &nonblock);
```

Comment: Great link! I really needed it

Comment: link is dead. [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/gtpc2/cpp_ioctl.html](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/gtpc2/cpp_ioctl.html) might be a replacement